# Logging in FreeBSD kernel code

Tags: kernel, freebsd, logging

I am adding some custom cryptography in the FreeBSD kernel and it causes a panic. I would like to log some variable values in functions that don't appear in the crash files.

I used both printf and log functions but nothing shows in /var/log/messages or kern.log

```
log(LOG_DEBUG, "line 1012");
printf("line 1012\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

That's probably because your kernel panics before syslogd(8) gets a chance to write them to log files.

What you want is crashdumps, https://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/books/developers-handbook/kerneldebug.html#kerneldebug-obtain.  When you have the crashdump, you can view pre-panic messages like this:

dmesg -N /boot/kernel/kernel -M /var/crash/vmcore.last

And of course, when you have the crashdump, you can use kgdb to inspect variables directly.

Comment: Thanks. I do generate crash dumps and use kgdb, the problem is with functions that don't exist on the stack when the panic happens. I used your `dmesg`suggestion but it only shows boot logs. Any ideas?

Comment: Dmesg should show whatever your code printf-ed just before the crash.  As for functions - yeah, that's because of compiler optimizations.

You might also want to compile DDB and use it instead.